# Using javascript with beego

Tags: javascript, go, beego

I am new to beego and golang. I am developing a web application in beego. I am honestly not able to find out how to use javascript with beego.

For example:

On a particular page i am showing all users name from all department. Now i have a drop down box in that page that will show the various department present in database. Now when i select one of that department from drop down list i want to show only users belonging to that department.

I can get the index value of selected department using javascript but how to use this index in controller to use it in database query?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you only need to use

```
    param := c.GetString("param") // Get the request parameter "param"
```

to get the request parameter and do you logic and the return the result.

No specified Javascript code for beego.

Here is the demo code https://gist.github.com/lei-cao/a4004ccab8d528df575b